# Convert text date (March 21st 2020) to dd/mm/yyyy

Tags: date, powerbi, powerquery, m

I've imported an excel sheet into PowerBI and I'm trying to trying to transform the date column from text format (March 21st 2020, 00:00:000) into date format (21/03/2020).

Unfortunately when I select "detect type" it only selects text, and selecting "Date" presents an error. I've removed the ", 00:00:000" from the columns but still receiving an error message.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how I can transform this column into dd/mm/yyyy?

Many thanks,

Comment: In DAX or in the query editor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After removing the `, 00:00:000`, you can use a transformation like one of these to remove the `st` part in `21st` so that `March 21st 2020 --> March 21 2020`, which can be automatically converted to a date.

This transformation strips all characters except space and numbers after the first space:

```
each Text.BeforeDelimiter(_, " ") & Text.Select(_, {" ", "0".."9"})
```

This one deletes the two characters to the left of the last space:

```
each Text.ReplaceRange(_, Text.PositionOf(_, " ", Occurrence.Last)-2, 2, "")
```

The full query (using the first option) would look like this:

```
let
    Source = <Your Data Source>,
    Remove00 = Table.TransformColumns(Source, {{"DateText", each Text.BeforeDelimiter(_, ","), type text}}),
    StripOrdinal = Table.TransformColumns(Remove00, {{"DateText", each Text.BeforeDelimiter(_," ") & Text.Select(_, {" ","0".."9"}), type text}}),
    TextToDate = Table.TransformColumnTypes(StripOrdinal,{{"DateText", type date}})
in
    TextToDate
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use this PowerQuery Script:

```
let
    Source = Excel.Workbook(File.Contents("Dates.xlsx"), null, true),
    Sheet1_Sheet = Source{[Item="Sheet1",Kind="Sheet"]}[Data],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Sheet1_Sheet,{{"Column1", type text}}),
    #"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.SplitColumn(#"Changed Type", "Column1", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter(" ", QuoteStyle.Csv), {"Column1.1", "Column1.2", "Column1.3"}),
    #"Added Month" = Table.AddColumn(#"Split Column by Delimiter", "Month", each if [Column1.1] = "January" then 1 else if [Column1.1] = "February" then 2 else if [Column1.1] = "March" then 3 else if [Column1.1] = "April" then 4 else if [Column1.1] = "May" then 5 else if [Column1.1] = "June" then 6 else if [Column1.1] = "July" then 7 else if [Column1.1] = "August" then 8 else if [Column1.1] = "September" then 9 else if [Column1.1] = "October" then 10 else if [Column1.1] = "November" then 11 else if [Column1.1] = "December" then 12 else 0),
    #"Added Day" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Month", "Day", each Text.Select([Column1.2], {"0".."9"})),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Day",{"Column1.1", "Column1.2"}),
    #"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Removed Columns",{{"Column1.3", "Year"}}),
    #"Changed Type2" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Renamed Columns",{{"Year", Int64.Type}, {"Month", Int64.Type}, {"Day", Int64.Type}}),
    #"Inserted Merged Column" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type2", "Date", each Text.Combine({Text.From([Day], "de-DE"), "/", Text.From([Month], "de-DE"), "/", Text.From([Year], "de-DE")}), type text),
    #"Changed Type3" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Inserted Merged Column",{{"Date", type date}}),
    #"Removed Columns2" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Changed Type3",{"Year", "Month", "Day"})
in
    #"Removed Columns2"
```

The conversion to your final data format is depending on your local settings and is usally done outside PowerQuery.

Answer (score 0):

`Date.From(Text.Combine(Splitter.SplitTextByAnyDelimiter({"st ","nd ","rd ","th "})([Attribute]),"-"))`

This above code could work as well, but be careful of the month of August. Maybe you can replace "August" with "Aug" before you do the conversion, just so you don't get an error on the months of August.